# Pycurl error: "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"

Tags: php, installation, redhat

When I try to install PHP 7.2 on redhat 6.8, this error appears:

```
Not loading "rhnplugin" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "product-id" plugin
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Loading "search-disabled-repos" plugin
Loading "subscription-manager" plugin
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Config time: 0.131
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php72/mirror error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: remi-php72. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score 0):

"remi" repository provides PHP 7.2 but only for latest 6.10.

> This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

You need to fix this first to be able to update to 6.10

> Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php72/mirror error was

As this URl works, you need to fix your network issue.